# How can I transfer this script from pinescript Version 2 to 5

Tags: pine-script

I found this pine script version 2on tradingview and would like to convert it to version 5 but I can't.

```
smma(src, length) =>
    smma = na(smma[1]) ? ta.sma(src, length) : (smma[1] * (length - 1) + src) / length
    smma
```

Answer (score 0):

```
smma(src, length) => 

   var float smma = 0.
   smma = na(smma[1]) ? ta.sma(src, length) : (smma[1] * (length - 1) + src) / length smma
```